# PowerBuilder Classic 12.5 - Double buffering, Vertical Sync

Tags: powerbuilder, doublebuffered, vertical-sync

Since i have lots of controls(buttons,dropdowns, gridviews) on a single form, the drawing seems to lag when fetching data from db, or i notice some screen tearing/lag when the control gets data from database and are drawn.

Now i have done some graphics in java and c++ programming, and know that double buffering/vertical sync or whatever is needed does help allot, but have no clue how to do this in powerbuilder.

Anyone here with experience in powerbuilder **classic**, know how to do this? 
the programming language is powerscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this, but another solution could be to set the redrawing your form until it is finished loading datas from the database. This way you could also avoid lag/flickr.

Function: SetRedraw 
Link: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37783.1200/html/dwref/PSFSetRedrawdw.htm

Answer (score 0):

Are the graphics loaded into a datawindow control? (check if the column has the 'display as bitmap' checkbox checked).  You can experiment with the SetRedraw method to 'turn off' painting of the screen/control until all the data is loaded.